# showing that if there is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which is isomorphic to $S_4$, then it is a subgroup of $U(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to show that there is no subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which is isomorphic to $S_4$.
I'm doing a proof by contradiction; Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which is isomorphic to $S_4$. I saw that we can conclude then that $G$ is a subgroup of $U(2)$. Why is that right? How can I show that?

I'll be thankful for having answers.

Comment: Two proofs that $GL_2(\Bbb C)$ has no such subgroup [are given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1347567/81360). Note that the existence of such a subgroup is equivalent to the existence of an injective homomorphism $\rho:S_4 \to GL_2(\Bbb C)$.

Comment: Where did you see that "we can conclude that $G$ is a subgroup of $U(2)$"?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$. Define a new inner product on $\Bbb C^n$ via $(v,w) := \sum_{g \in G}\langle gv,gw\rangle$, where $\langle-,-\rangle$ is the standard inner product (check that this is actually an inner product). By construction, $(v,w)$ is $G$-invariant, i.e. $(v,w)=(gv,gw)$ for all $v,w \in \Bbb C^n, g \in G$. This implies that if we choose an orthonormal basis for this inner product, $G$ will be contained in $U(n)$.

(This is a standard argument in representation theory.)

Comment: This shows that $G$ is *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $U(2)$, but it doesn't actually show that the group of matrices respects the standard inner product over $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann that is true. I think it shouldn't make a difference if the goal is to show that $\mathrm{GL}_2(\Bbb C)$ doesn't contain a subgroup isomorphic to $S_4$.

Comment: That's a fair point